# Raid1 disk degraded after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, mdadm, raid1, rackspace-cloud

I'm testing a Rackspace cloud server and have two Cloud Block Storage volumes set up in a Raid1 configuration.

There are no system files on these volumes, they're purely for storage.  Everything appears to work fine until I reboot the server.

After doing that the second volume is removed and labeled as "faulty spare" under state.

Any idea what could be causing this?

---

UPDATE: 12/24

I've discussed this Rackspace support and the problem is still unresolved.  They think that the Raid may not be being fully deactivated before shutdown and suggested I try adding `barrier=0` to the fstab options which didn't help.

I also tried unmounting the Raid volume before rebooting again, but when that happened the first volume went into "faulty spare" this time around.

The following are my fstab options:

```
proc          /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid           0       0
/dev/xvda1    /               ext3    errors=remount-ro,barrier=0   0       1
/dev/xvdc1    none            swap    sw                            0       0
/dev/md0      /mnt/var1       ext4    defaults,noatime,barrier=0    0       0
```

And the following is the result of `mdadm --query --detail /dev/md0` after reboot

```
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Fri Dec 21 17:42:10 2012
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 104791936 (99.94 GiB 107.31 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 104791936 (99.94 GiB 107.31 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Dec 24 21:24:26 2012
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 1
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : test-prod:0  (local to host test-prod)
           UUID : a6b73196:be9fb090:5cc71f0a:205b6fb2
         Events : 148

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       2     202       48        1      active sync   /dev/xvdd

       0     202       16        -      faulty spare   /dev/xvdb
```

After reboot, I can run `mdadm --remove /dev/md0 /dev/xvdb; mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/xvdb` and the array rebuilds successfully until the next reboot.

Comment: Why not discuss this problem with the RackSpace people? They would most likely be the quickest and best source of help for you.

Comment: Is the shutdown for reboot clean?

Comment: @DaveM Sorry for the delayed response.  But yes, the reboot is clean.

Comment: I've updated the original post with more information after testing and talking to Rackspace support.  Still can't nail down the problem unfortunately.